# issues with menu items displaying incorrectly & alignment changes when attempts to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble with menu icons aligning to the right.

So far I have my logo on the left and the menu icons on the right, however their order is reversed. Instead of home, portfolio, contact it displays as contact, portfolio, home. I understand that this is because the li is set to float left. However, when I float the links to the right to have them display in the correct order, the entire links menu will move to the left, leaving a large gap to the right of the last link. (I want the links to display on the far right of the header browser window and my logo on the far left). In my attemps to fix the order of the links, I messed up their positioning within the header.

Currently it is optimised for mobile devices and re-sizing the window will create a hamburger icon and the menu drops down with the text centered left. I want this unchanged, I just want my links to be positioned in the correct order and far right as possible on browser windows in the correct order.

I also had a friend (using a larger monitor) have the links show up in the middle of the header which I am not sure why that is happening as they display correctly on my screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D 
Codepen with the preview is here; http://codepen.io/AnishaDesigns/pen/wdzNQq

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Coolvetica'; /*Font name*/
src: url('coolvetica.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

body {
  background-color: #E6E9EC;
}
ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'coolvetica';
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

li{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  background: #A62841;
  margin-right: 20px;

}
li a{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #E6E9EC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #A62841;
}

header #branding{
  margin:0px;
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 20px;
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){

.menu-icon{
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background:url("images/menu-icon.svg") no-repeat center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 16px;
  }

header nav ul{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #A62841;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header nav ul.open{
  height: auto;
}

h1{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

header nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}
header nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
header{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited the code and added float:left; to li and changed to width: auto; for ul.

```
ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'coolvetica';
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

li{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  background: #A62841;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/athira151292/pen/JNRzjo

Comment: Perfect. Is there any way to move the links in browser view more to the right? like as close to the edge that the logo is but just the opposite side :) hope im making sense!

Comment: I have edited the codepen. Added width: auto; for ul. Please check.
http://codepen.io/athira151292/pen/JNRzjo
If you got it, please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `float:left` to li elements and assign `width:auto` to the ul element. If you want fix some width for ul then use `max-width:50%` for that.

```
ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  width:auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'coolvetica';
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
 }

 li{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  background: #A62841;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rv1breax/)

Comment: Yes, this works but on mobile devices the menu changes now to not be 100% of the device width and the links to the left if that makes sense. Basically I like how the menu appears in my original coding but I want those two links switched around so they display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

change the width of ul from 50% to auto and float:left